# White Screen on YouTube video on Internet Explorer IE9 with Fancybox

Tags: youtube, fancybox

I'm using a Shopify shopping cart that includes a fancybox script for images.  It's works great across the board for images, and I've added some scripts to get it to work with YouTube videos as well.  I'm not awesome with script, but it is working for FireFox & Chrome - but on IE9 (not sure if any other versions) I'm getting a white screen that covers the video.

http://cycletek.com/pages/test

Thanks for your help!

Comment: it works fine in IE7, check your compatibility view settings

Comment: I checked them, not working on IE9 at all.